# Is it possible to disable the timestamps for the 'attach' method in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, many-to-many

Is it possible to disable the timestamps for the `attach` method in Laravel? Of course, it's normal situation to use it in  the pivot table, but if I remove it I have an SQL Error. Even if I don't use `withTimestamps` method.

Does anybody knows the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable timestaps for any model:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Or you can add this before persisting any data:

```
$model->timestamps = false;
$model->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Place public $timestamps = false; in your model

```
class Pivot extends Model {
  protected $table = "pivots";
  public $timestamps = false;
}
```